# speech_recognition.listen() is not working

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

whenever i try to run the speech recognition's listen function it gets stuck over there , i tried to debug it but still it gets stuck over there , while over there , cmd line also won't print anything or display any error:
the code :

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r=sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    r.pause_threshold=1
    print('say')
    audio=r.listen(source)
    text=r.recognize_google(audio,language='en-in')
    print(f'user said:{text}')
```

Terminal:

```
PS D:\Desktop AI> & "d:/Desktop AI/env/Scripts/Activate.ps1"
(env) PS D:\Desktop AI> python -u "d:\Desktop AI\Wednesday\tempCodeRunnerFile.py"
say
```

I tried to convert my speech into a text form using Speech Recognition library , but instead it always gets stuck at the listen() function , i tried to reinstall Speech Recognition but it's of no use

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with speech recognition. Also i had issues accessing microphone due to package installation on the device.

```
model, decode, utils = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir = 'snakers4/silero-models',
                model='silero_stt', language='en',
                device=device, trust_repo=True)
def testing():
    r =sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone(sample_rate=16000) as mic:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic)
        print('start speaking...')

        audio1 = r.listen(mic)
        audio = io.BytesIO(audio1.get_wav_data())
        audio = AudioSegment.from_file(audio)
        x = torch.FloatTensor(audio.get_array_of_samples()).view(1, -1)
        x = x.to(device)
        z = model(x)
        print('you:', decode(z[0]))
```